# React using Firebase Realtime Database's onValue reads data once every file save, but not on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

When I first load my app `onValue` will correctly get my DB info and I'm able to display the values in my app, but when I refresh the browser page the information is lost, and thus nothing displays. If I change something non-functional in the code so that React updates its local server, `onValue` is used again and the DB snapshot is retrieved again.

Since the value is lost when the page is refreshed I assumed I needed to store the snapshot data in state. But when I introduced `setState`, to captured the value returned from `onValue(gamesRef, (snapshot) => ...`, React errors out and says there is an infinite loop. I'm guessing the React `setState` inside the `onValue` is causing this but I'm not sure why.

Can anyone give me some advice about how to get either of these paths working?
Thanks!

Comment: You're going to need to load your data in a `useEffect`, not in the body of the component. See https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects

Comment: Can you offer a generic answer in code? I've seen I cannot use `useState` inside `useEffect` without triggering a rendering, resulting in an infinite loop. I need `onValue` to update the page if anything changes in the database. I don't understand what value I can set the `useEffect` dependency to in order to update the page only when the database is updated - which is what I thought `onValue` is supposed to take care of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Nicholas Tower](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3794812/nicholas-tower)'s vague but helpful comment I was able to figure this out eventually. (Turns out he's answered this question a few times before).

Firebase's realtime database `onValue` needs to be inside `useEffect`. Inside `useEffect` I had to set state with `useState` even though you are warned against doing that as it may cause an infinite loop; `useState` triggers rendering, rendering calls `useEffect` which calls `useState` again.

The only way this works is if you set a `useEffect` dependency array at the end. My linter demanded I put something in the array and not leave it blank, so I used `props` as the only update condition in the dependency array.

Pseudo-code:

```
function Lobby(props) {
    const [ gameSnapshot, setGameSnapshot ] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {

        const gamesRef = ref(db, 'games');
        
        onValue(gamesRef, (snapshot) => {
            const listOfGames = Object.keys(snapshot.val()).map(gameUid =>
                // do things / build JSX markup using data
            );
            setGameSnapshot(listOfGames);
        });
    },[props]);


    return (
        <div className="Lobby">
            {gameSnapshot}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Lobby;
```